# Cant connect to selenium over Tor

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tor

I am using selenium in Kali to connect to Tor, the path is correct for the TOR package (i double checked).

Keep getting this error, been driving me crazy. Any input would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Can't read the picture and I'm sure as hell not going to copy the image, put it into an image program and then zoom in. No idea why people think that presenting text as an image is ever a clever idea.

Comment: it said the only way to post picture is this, wouldn't let me do it other way. I hate it too. Seems like you need to be a 10 star or something to embed images. Seems like its been fixed now. Appreciate the feedback.

Comment: My while point is that the original stack trace and all are **text**. Don't post a picture even in the most pristine of all conditions. There's literally not a single advantage doing so.